# Using minikube to pull image from local Docker registry (with self-signed CA certificate)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

Using minikube to pull image from local Docker registry (with self-signed CA certificate)

I'd like to be able to run minikube so that it can access a local docker registry using a self signed CA certificate. Ideally the process should be automated so that I can use a `*deployment.yaml` file to pull the required image without intervention.

At the moment I'm using a workaroud as follows:

```sh
#ssh into the minikube instance
sudo minikube ssh
#create a folder for the certificate
sudo mkdir /etc/docker/certs.d/dave.local:5000
#copy the crt file from the registry computer to the minikube instance
sudo scp user@192.168.1.2:/home/dave/certs/domain.crt /etc/docker/certs.d/dave.local:5000
#then check login
docker login dave.local:5000
#then pull image so that it's already in minikube
docker pull dave.local:5000/davedockerimage
```

I then edit the  `*deployment.yaml`  with `imagePullPolicy: Never` .  When I then run `sudo kubectl create -f dave-deployment.yaml`it finds `dave.local:5000/davedockerimage`locally on minikube it uses the already pulled image.

If `imagePullPolicy: Always` . The image pull fails in minikube.

I've been through a range of tutorials/stack overflow answers and have been unable to crack this. Any help appreciated.

Comment: How does it fail?  If you need to `docker login`, does adding an appropriate `imagePullSecret:` help?

Comment: I've tried using `imagePullSecret:` and that seems to work, but I get an issue with the certificate

`Failed to pull image 
"dave.local:5000/davedockerimage": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error 
response from daemon: Get https://dave.local:5000/v2/: x509: 
certificate signed by unknown authority`

Comment: Once you moved the certs to /etc/docker/certs.d/dave.local:5000 did you reload docker daemon to use the certificate?

Comment: No, I didn't have to restart docker

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Running insecure connections wasn't an option for me, so I followed these [minikube certificates docs](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/untrusted_certs/). This configures minikube to trust certificates issued by your internal CA.

First copy the CA certs in PEM format into minikube's `certs` directory:

```bash
mkdir -p "${HOME}/.minikube/certs"
cp my-ca-certs-file.pem "${HOME}/.minikube/certs/"
```

Next, restart minikube with the `--embed-certs` option to sync certificates.

```bash
minikube stop
minikube start --embed-certs
```

After that, try pull images using a deployment or statefulset.
If you receive an authentication error, you may need to configure `regcred` so kubernetes can authenticate with your custom registry.
To do that, create a secret that kubernetes knows to reference when authenticating with your docker registry.
These instructions are adapted from Kubernetes docs, "[Pull an Image from a Private Registry](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/)".

```bash
docker login dave.local:5000
# Enter your credentials when prompted.

# This copies your cached token into a kubernetes secret.
kubectl create secret generic regcred \
    --from-file=.dockerconfigjson="${HOME}/.docker/config.json" \
    --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

Then your deployments should be able to pull any referenced images from `dave.local:5000/...`

Answer (score 0):

As a alternative for using self signed certificate in minikube you can start minikube with insecure-registry option like below:

```
minikube start --insecure-registry="dave.local:5000"
```

Comment: I tried that previously, but the pull failed as it then looked for `http://dave.local:5000/`  rather than `https://dave.local:5000/`